# Reversing a function involving a modulus arithmetics

Tags: math, reverse-engineering, modulus

I'm trying to reverse-engineer a function to get the input. Suppose we know the output (x). Is it possible to get the input (z)? 
The code for the function is as follows

```
uint myfunc (uint z){
    var uint_1 = 1372797859u;
    var uint_2 = 1114478491u;
    ulong a = (ulong)z;
    uint x  = 1u;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i += 1)
    {
        if ((uint_2 & 1u) != 0u)
        {
            x  = (uint)((ulong)x  * a % (ulong)uint_1);
        }
        a = a * a % (ulong)uint_1;
        uint_2 >>= 1;
    }
    return x ;
}
```

Suppose we know the value of the output (x) this function throws at us, say 35500.

Considering `x  = (uint)((ulong)x  * a % (ulong)uint_1);` 
It is obvious that `x` on left hand side is greater than the one on the right hand side as we start with `uint x  = 1u;`
If we had something like `x  = a % (ulong)uint_1;`, we could just check the value of `a` by brute force (starting `a` with 1 and incrementing it with 1). The code is complex and I don't know if it is even possible to reverse-engineer this function.

Comment: Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Comment: please do not post screen shots of code with ligatures, it's really non standard.  Just use SOs inbuilt syntax highlighting.

Comment: You could just analyze the algorithm to see what it computes. I think I know based on a quick look at it.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I would like to know. It would help me learn. Thanks

Comment: @f9fella: I wrote an answer. I can expand on it if you are interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only is it possible to get the input z, you can use your function `myfunc` with one little change to get it: simply change

```c
var uint_2 = 1114478491u;
```

to

```c
var uint_2 = 42451u;
```

To elaborate:

The function `myfunc` is performing modular exponentiation with a fixed exponent. Specifically, it is computing z<sup>1114478491</sup> mod 1372797859.

Also, 1372797859 = 25057 * 54787, both factors are primes. This may be recognized as an instance of the [RSA cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) with toy-sized parameters. We may regard `myfunc` as performing an RSA encryption<sup>*</sup> and therefore 1114478491 as the encrypt exponent. Therefore, using the procedure outlined in the Wikipedia page we can compute the decrypt exponent which turns out to be 42451. Since `myfunc` is just a modular exponentiation function, merely by changing 1114478491u to 42451u we have the decrypt function which is the inverse.

<sup>*In RSA an encrypt and decrypt exponent exist, but which role is assigned to which exponent is arbitrary. However, in actual implementations the encrypt exponent is usually small, almost always 65537 in fact, and such a small exponent can only play the role of the encrypt exponent or the system is easily broken.</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply with answer. I would like an expanded explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SMT solver directly, or via symbolic execution engine to find function inputs based on its outputs.

For instance, you can re-write your function in C and use [KLEE](http://klee.github.io/) to find the answer:

```
#include <klee/klee.h>

uint myfunc (uint z) {
  ...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int input, output;
  input = klee_int("input");
  output = myfunc(input);
  klee_assert(output == 35500);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile this code with clang to emit LLVM IR:

```
clang -c -emit-llvm -o main.bc main.c
```

Then run KLEE on it

```
klee main.bc
```

And then analyze results using `ktest-tool`.